# why is my program not outputting info after executing it

Tags: c, file-io

I am currently working on a log parsing program in C, and on the recommendation of a few people, i decided to replace fscanf with a combination of fgets and scanf, but instead of returning the last line of the log file like it had done before, the program will just produce a blank line then exit afterwards, I am relatively new to C (started teaching myself a few weeks ago) so I may just be overlooking some dumb mistake, but if anyone could help me with this i would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
void main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  FILE *fd;
  char *name;
  name = getenv("MCEXEC_PLAYERNAME");
  char *filename;
  filename = malloc(sizeof "/home/minecraft/freedonia/playerdata/deathlog-.txt" - 1 +     strlen(name) + 1);
  if (!filename) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  sprintf(filename,"/home/minecraft/freedonia/playerdata/deathlog-%s.txt",name);
  char *buff;
  buff = malloc(1024);
  char *finbuff;
  finbuff = malloc(1024);
  if ((fd = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL)
  {
    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while(!feof(fd))
  {
      memset(buff, 0x00, 1024);
      memset(finbuff, 0x00, 1024);
     // fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]\n", buff);
      fgets(buff, 1024, fd);
      sscanf(buff, "%[^\n]\n", finbuff);
   }
    printf("%s\n", finbuff);
  }
  else
  printf( "fail" );
}
```

and for the version that worked, it was pretty much just the commented out part in the while loop, along with finbuff not being included in the program

```
   while(!feof(fd))
    {
      memset(buff, 0x00, 1024);
      fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]\n", buff);
    }
```

Comment: `scanf(buff, "%[^\n]\n", finbuff);` is not right , lookup `sprintf`

Comment: @Keety what do you think is wrong with scanf?

Comment: ok found out that sscanf makes it so instead of sitting and waiting, the program just exits normally, although it still produces a blank line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to stick with the present code only then pls check this line once

memset(buff, 0x00, 1024);

I think some problem is here , if it is possible for u to define the "buff " as static allocation not dynamically then try that ( char buff[256] = {0}) .

OR

if u can opt this to get the last line :

```
int main(){
const char *file = "in";
FILE *in = fopen(file, "r");
if (in != NULL){
int bytes = 0;
int nl = 0;
while(fseek(in, --bytes, SEEK_END) == 0){
if (fgetc(in) == '\n' && ++nl > 2){
break;
}
}
char line[ARG_MAX];
fgets(line, sizeof line, in);
fputs(line, stdout);
fclose(in);
}
return 0;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for your advice, actually ended up using the different method to find the last line and it worked perfectly!